# Why java compile is not invoking a method which is present inside a method

Tags: java, cucumber

I am working on Cucumber java project and which is in very initial phase . While writing the code in step definition file. I found there is data required in Step N which is present only in Step N-1 i.e Sharing of data between cucumber test steps .As the project is in very initial phase . I thought implementation  setter() and getter() method will work for me i.e is setter() I will set the value of variable and the call the getter() method whenever i need this data 
Kindly find the actual implementation.

StepDefinition:

```
    @Given("^recent destination list$")
    public void list_of_recent_destinations_is_non_empty() throws Throwable {
        gm.appLaucher();
        gm.setValue_searchAddressOrName_HomeScreen("Wemmel");
        gm.click_selectAddress_HomeScreen();
        gm.click_driveButton_OnMapScreen();
        gm.click_clearRouteButton_OnMapScreen();
        gm.setValue_searchAddressOrName_HomeScreen("Ukkel, Beersel,1180");
        gm.click_selectAddress_HomeScreen();
        gm.click_driveButton_OnMapScreen();
        gm.click_clearRouteButton_OnMapScreen();

        gm.setValue_searchAddressOrName_HomeScreen("Sint-Jansplein Brussel, 1000");
        gm.click_selectAddress_HomeScreen();
        gm.click_driveButton_OnMapScreen();
        gm.click_clearRouteButton_OnMapScreen();
        gm.click_mainMenuButton_OnMapScreen();
        gm.tap_recentDestinationButton_OnMainMenuScreen();
        gm.tap_editListButton_RecentDestinationScreen();
        List<MobileElement> em1= gm.get_recentDestinaList_EditListScreen();
        System.out.println("____________________________________________"+em1.size());
        int numOfElement=em1.size()-2;
        boolean status =em1.size()>0;
        Assert.assertEquals(true,status);




    }


    @When("^user selects one or more $")
    public void user_selects_one_or_more_recent_destinations() throws Exception {
        List<MobileElement> em1= gm.get_recentDestinaList_EditListScreen();
        System.out.println("____________________________________________"+em1.size());
        Iterator<MobileElement> it=em1.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next().getText());
        }


        String str= gm.getIndividualElement_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen(2);
        System.out.println(str+"%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");


    }

    @When("^user deletes address$")
    public void user_deletes_selected_addresses() throws Exception {

         gm.setValueForOtherSteps(gm.get_recentDestinaList_EditListScreen().size());


        gm.deleteIndividualElememnt_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen(2);

    }

    @Then("^recent\\(s\\) is\\(are\\) removed from list$")
    public void recent_destination_s_is_are_removed_from_list() throws Exception {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        System.out.println(gm.getValueFromOtherStep()+"Intermidiate value from Step definition class");
        int x=gm.getSize_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen();
        System.out.println(x+"+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        String strLastElement=gm.getIndividualElement_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen(3);
        String strSecondLast=gm.getIndividualElement_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen(2);
        int y=gm.getSize_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen();
        Assert.assertEquals(x, y);
//        Assert.assertEquals(strLastElement, strSecondLast);
//        gm.tap_editListButton_RecentDestinationScreen();
//
//        gm.deleteAllElement_recentDestinationList_EditListScreen();


    }

    @Then("^recent desorted in temporal order$")
    public void recent_destinations_list_is_sorted_in_temporal_order() throws Exception {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

    }
```

In Above gm is object of GMain class kindly find the implementation as below

```
class GMain{

  public void setValueForOtherSteps(Object obj) throws IOException {
      System.out.println(obj+"Intermediate values to verify +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
     getValueFromOtherStep();

 }


  public Object getValueFromOtherStep()
  {
      if(getValue() instanceof Integer) {
          System.out.println((Integer)getValue()+" test");
          return (Integer) getValue();
      }
      else if (getValue() instanceof String)
      {
          return (String) getValue();
      }
      else if (getValue() instanceof Boolean)
      {
          return (Boolean) getValue();
      }
      else {
          System.out.print(getValue());
          return "";
      }

}
```

So as we call setValueForOtherSteps() from stepDefinition ,Control comes to GMain class method public void setValueForOtherSteps(Object obj) but why transfer goes back to caller without calling getValueFromOtherStep() method

I know this may be silly but Any kind of help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are those your full methods, or did you edit them for posting the question? I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: No these are not actual method but its almost same as the method which i used in my implementation but in case  if you still need full method kindly find below                                                                                                public void setValueForOtherSteps(Object obj)
  {
      System.out.println(obj+"Intermediate values to verify +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
      getValueFromOtherStep();
      
      
  }

Comment: Can you update your question with that code? It's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: Yes its full method . I have issue with method ab() which is not being invoke .I can see in debug mode control is coming to setValueForOtherStep(Object obj) but it gets transer to the caller which is present in Stepdefinition without invoking ab() method

Comment: please suggest if still you need actual code .Thanks for consideration

Comment: Actual code would be good since I cannot reproduce it.